# Why am I getting java.lang.NullPointerException while doing linked list traversal?

Tags: java, linked-list, stack, runtime-error, traversal

So I am trying to make a program that uses linked list. I am getting a runtime error when I try to run it though. I am completely confused and have literally no idea on how to fix this. There is apparently something wrong with my traversal method in MyLinkedList class.

Error:  `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
          at MyLinkedList.traversal(MyLinkedList.java:68)
          at MyLinkedListClient.main(MyLinkedListClient.java:13)`

It highlights this line of code: `result = temp.getElement() + "-->";`

I apologize if I have asked this in a poorly written manner. My 2nd time using this website so hopefully I do not chewed out too badly >< lol Oh and sorry if my code is formatted weird, it got weird trying to get it to look like code in my post lol.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
public class MyLinkedListClient {

public static void main(String [] args) {

  MyLinkedList<String> myList = new MyLinkedList<String>();

  myList.addFirst("MSP");
  myList.addFirst("RST");
  myList.addFirst("LAX");
  myList.addFirst("PHL");


    System.out.println(myList.traversal());

    System.out.println(myList.removeFirst() + " is removed.");

  System.out.println(myList.traversal());

}

}//end of class




public class MyLinkedList<E> {

//instance variables
private Node<E> head;
//private Node<E> tail 
private int size;

//constructor
public MyLinkedList() {
head = null;
//do something with tail
size = 0;
}   

public boolean isEmpty() {
  if(head == null)
     return true;

  return false;
}

public int size() {
  return size;
}

public void addFirst (E element) {
  Node<E> temp = new Node<E>(element, null);

  //do something with tail

  if(isEmpty())
     temp.setNext(head);
  else {
     temp.setNext(head);
     head = temp;
  }
  size++;
}


public E removeFirst() throws EmptyListException {
  if(isEmpty())
     throw new EmptyListException("The list is empty.");

  Node<E> temp = head; //step 1

  head = head.getNext(); //step 2

  temp.setNext(null); //step 3

  size--;

  return temp.getElement(); //step 4
}

public String traversal() {

  if(size() == 0)
     return "Empty list.";

  Node<E> temp = head;

  String result = "Head -->";

  int i = size();

  while (i > 0) {
     result = temp.getElement() + "-->";
     temp = temp.getNext();
     i--;
  }

  return result;
}

/*
public boolean search( E element) {

}   
*/

}//end of class
```

Comment: Most likely the immediate cause is that the `temp` variable is `null` and you are trying to dereference it.  However, the fastest way to get to the root cause of _your_ code is probably to use a debugger and see what is wrong.

Comment: When the list is empty, you never assign the new node to `head`, so the list never has a head node and is always empty (according to your `isEmpty` method)

Comment: You don't need the if else statement in addFirst. Just do temp.setNext(head);
     head = temp;